# Python gives me the index numbers instead of the input in the list.

Tags: python, list

Python gives me the index numbers instead of the input in the list. I'm trying to get the user to give input and then have it store that into a printed list. How do I fix it?

```
number_of_grades = int(input('How many quizzes have you had?'))

grade_list = []

for grades in range(number_of_grades):
    input('Please input a grade from the quiz.')
    grade_list.insert(0, grades)

print(grade_list)
```

It works just fine up until it needs to be printed.

Comment: What do you think happens to the value returned by the second `input`?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are not assigning your second input to a variable!, then you are just inserting the index used in the `for` loop.

```
number_of_grades = int(input('How many quizzes have you had?'))
grade_list = [] 
for grades in range(number_of_grades): 
    value = input('Please input a grade from the quiz.') 
    grade_list.insert(0, value)
print(grade_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: Great!!, it just happens a lot of times to me. Glad to help you.